# Private class specialization error

Tags: c++, c++11, clang

During compilation the code below in clang i have warning (in vc++ it works fine):

> warning : explicit specialization of 'Helper' within class scope is a
>   Microsoft extension [-Wmicrosoft]

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

enum class Car { BMW };

class C
{
    static void Method() { puts("inner");}
};

template<typename T>
class BaseClass
{
private:
    template<typename V> 
    struct Helper;

    template<>
    struct Helper<Car>
    {
        typedef C InnerType;
        static const char* Name() { return "Car"; }
    };

    typedef Helper<T> Info;
    typedef typename Info::InnerType InnerType;

private:
    T v;

protected:
    BaseClass()
    { }

public:
    T Value() const { return v; }
    std::string Name() const { return Info::Name(); }
    static void Print() { InnerType::Method(); }
};


class MyCar : public BaseClass<Car>
{
public:
    MyCar() : BaseClass() {}
};

int main()
{
    MyCar a;
    printf("%s\n", a.Name().c_str());
//  a.Print();
}
```

I have tried to move the specialization of Helper class outside `BaseClass` to be compatible with standard:

```
template<> template<>
struct BaseClass<Car>::Helper<Car>
{
    typedef C InnerType;
    static const char* Name() { return "Car"; }
};
```

But now I have compilation error:

> error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'BaseClass::Helper'

If I remove the line: `typedef typename Info::InnerType InnerType;` (and related usage in function `Print`) then everything works fine.

Is it possible to fix this error ? I would like to keep my `Helper` class as private.

Comment: You can add a dummy template parameter to turn the *explicit specialization* (the *full specialization*) into a *partial specialization*. The latter are allowed in the Standard in class scope.

Comment: See http://www.open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg21/docs/cwg_active.html#727

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string>

enum class Car { BMW };

class C
{
    static void Method() { puts("inner");}
};

template<typename T>
class BaseClass
{
private:
    template<typename V> 
    struct Helper;

    template<typename V>
    using Info = Helper<V>;

    template<typename V>
    using InnerType = typename Info<V>::InnerType;


private:
    T v;

protected:
    BaseClass()
    { }

public:
    T Value() const { return v; }
    std::string Name() const { return Info<T>::Name(); }
    static void Print() { InnerType<T>::Method(); }
};

template<> template<>
struct BaseClass<Car>::Helper<Car>
{
    typedef C InnerType;
    static const char* Name() { return "Car"; }
};


class MyCar : public BaseClass<Car>
{
public:
    MyCar() : BaseClass() {}
};

int main()
{
    MyCar a;
    printf("%s\n", a.Name().c_str());
    //a.Print();
}
```

(gcc 5.1/clang 3.6, -std=C++11)

The program prints "Car".